# SP2013 Last modified date wrong in search results - day and month are inverted

Tags: 2013, document-library, search, search-results, date-time

We have a problem with the search results "Last modified Date".
So if i take a look at the document and look at the last modified document i see   `"06/10/2014"`.

This is correct cause the document was edited last time on 10th of June. 
When I start the search for this document I'll get this information in the last modified date `"10/06/2014"`.

I've also changed my language and region settings to German and made a new search. The result of the search gives me `"06.10.2014"` as last modified date. So here SP seems to have problems to display the correct date.

Has anybody of you a solution for this case?
Many thanks in advance. 
BR Michael

Answer (score 1):

we have the same problem at one of our clients.
It has nothing to do with date formats etc.

The document has the last modified time set to "2012-08-02 13:50:08" (item property which is year-month-day).
If i query for the document with the search query tool it returns the raw data for the last modified property "2012-02-08T13:50:00.0000000Z" - and this is obviously wrong.

There are multiple errors:
- month and day are switched in search
- it does not show the correct time (cause we are not UTC - thus 13:50 is the local time)

It only happens for some documents, not all. And only if day is lower than month.

Same issue seems to be described here: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/c2a34855-d7d7-440f-898c-fcd288d79ff3/document-modification-monthday-swapping-in-search-results?forum=sharepointsearch

Thus, this seems to be a bug.

Regards,
Sascha

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confused with date formats. Please check with JavaScript in Display Template, use proper Date Conversion(Parse it).
May be the date is correct but only DATE FORMAT is not right.

[Check this link](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp) for JavaScript Date Objects

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing similar issue but might not be the exact scenario.

I have a document where modified date doesnt gets updated when if user modifies the item inside of the excel document. Weird thing is when i open that document library in " Open with explorer mode" It is correctly listing the correct modified date. So after doing lots of research and opening up a ticket with microsoft this is what i found:

1. Issue might be related to the distributed Cache services not working properly if you are using Sp2013 ( microsoft asked for my log files and they could point out List guid throwing error related to distributed cache)
2. Other find i discovered was the behavior was only experienced on users who were using Windows Xp as there OS. I my self an using windows 7 i had no issues.

We are still working on microsoft on this, if you have experienced such behavior keep me posted.

Answer (score -1):

http://sharepointjournal.com/2014/08/28/sharepoint-2013-last-modifiedchanged-showing-wrong-dates-regional-settings/

Hope this solution helps you.

Definetly related to the managed metadata property reading the doc properties modified date instead of the column .